# Prevent play store from showing me updates on an application installed through another store

Tags: google-play-store, amazon-appstore, kindle-for-android

Recently Amazon disabled all in-app purchases from their apps distributed through the Play Store.

As I'm a frequent user of the kindle app, and not a fan on switching to my browser instead of in-app purchases, I've opted to install Amazon AppStore and through it the Kindle for Android app.

Now, though, the Play Store always displays an update available for the Kindle for Android app.

What I would like, is a way to tell the play store not to try and manage this application.

I've already disabled automatic updates, but the issue with this is that every time I touch "Update all applications" I have to deal with a popup to confirm I want to ignore KFA updates.

It's not that big of a deal, but i'm wary of mistake on my part later down the line.

EDIT: My phone is not currently rooted, and the manufacturer enforces a factory reset to unlock the bootloader. As it stands I'd prefer not to have to root the phone (Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro)

Comment: In the switching process was the Kindle app always installed? If yes I would try to uninstall it and then reinstall it via Amazon app store. If you have adb enabled you can do `adb uninstall -k com.amazon.kindle` to uninstall the app but keep the data.

Comment: No, I uninstalled it from the application list of the OS. Then installed it from the Amazon AppStore. I kind of suspect, that they are using the same package id and signature on the two stores.

Answer (score 2):

With root access via magisk, you can use this module to exclude an app from play store updates

https://github.com/yuk7/playstore-excl-upd

Comment: Thanks for the option, but my phone is not currently rooted, and the manufacturer enforces a factory reset to unlock the bootloader. As it stands I'd prefer not to have to root the phone, I'll add that to the question